# Can I, How do I, stop Chrome from asking to switch/continue Google Profiles when I use another account on Gmail or GDocs

Tags: google-workspace, google-chrome, google-account-profile

When I login to another of my Google Accounts, Chrome Asks if I want to switch/continue in that profile. I want to be able to stop this notification behaviour, because the pop up is annoying.

I do everything from a single google account and even if I am logging into another account for Gmail or docs purposes, I do not wish any chrome activity to be stored anywhere else. Only exception would be incognito mode, where no activity being stored is the goal.

To summarise I do not want Google Chrome to ask me if I want change to that profile and/or add it to my list of my profiles. And don't annoy me any more!

Picture of the notification seen in Chrome only:
"Continue in a new Chrome profile?"

[image]

Comment: [Same question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68701600/145173)

Comment: same question no longers has the solution unfortunately Chrome removed the flag from : 
chrome://flags/